# Why do i get this TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable python?

Tags: python, range, typeerror

Why does this type error?
Normally, I'd just now use `enumerate()`, but I specifically want to iterate in this given range:

```
r1 = (0,0,100,100)
r2 = (20,20,40,40)
r3 = (40,40,80,80)
these_objects = []
objects.append(r1)
objects.append(r2)
objects.append(r3)
objects_clone = copy.copy(these_objects)
iterations = int(len(objects_clone))-1
print(iterations)

for this_index, this_object in range(0, iterations):
    # ...
```

Exception:

```
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 50, in <module>
    for this_index, this_object in range(0, iterations):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range(0, iterations)` object produces integers, not tuples. You are asking the `for` loop to unpack each integer into two variables:

```
for this_index, this_object in range(0, iterations):
```

Unpacking an integer fails:

```
>>> this_index, this_object = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You can just iterate over the indices and extract objects in a second:

```
for this_index in range(iterations):
    this_object = objects_clone[this_index]
    # ...
```

If you wanted to enumerate over all objects except the last, perhaps you wanted to *slice* to ignore the last element:

```
for this_index, this_object in enumerate(objects_clone[:-1]):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index and the element together, you should indeed use `enumerate()`. That's what it's for. `range()`, on the other hand, gives you one object at a time: an integer. And, since there is only one object per integer, you can't unpack each integer into two objects. This is why `for i in range(num):` is such a common construct, while `for i,j in range(num):` is not.